# Remove some urls from markdown with typescript

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript, markdown

Using Typescript and Node v8, I am trying to process a markdown text and remove all the image URLs that follow a specific pattern:

- URLs that contain the word forbidden
- URLs with IP addresses

I am trying using this regular expression:

![([^]]+)]((.*(fordbidden|(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*)\

[This typescript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwE4GsAmIDuYAqBTAD1gF4AoGCyqigcgB1zqmAqGAQgG0BBAGx6zxoYAS0QBzPAF0AFAAsoUAA4AuAPSqEwYHkVRBGRMLCrRCCQDpFYMQEoGTFuw4AxEEgBGwtGjxgYBhCMRcSk5BRV1ADM3NE9vXxMQy2sbGHsHKlZOVw8vXxgASQAFYLNQ+SU1VQAOAAZzAEYG8wAmeoaAVkSy5Ns0xgzaAG5SUlBIWEJFPGA9ITJBynoBwazuPgEhUwkZCoiNLR05gKNuiytbdMW1nLifPxO-bdDUq9WnW7y-YtKd6VeVhkaCMMmNwNAYNFcvEwAUQhAYMQYKo2HQONIOAA9OiSSQAajskjo0mk5mY0ihsS89wAPtIAPzKDi1AC0AE5JABvBoAGgAzABfOjmGycwXM9lc3mCmxkuw2VRiOAjUiRACuYFmwnAMCQeDgIAAbnhPjDpIhUBhsMoYNAkEZbDa7Q6YJyVnqoGqkH54Mh0FgwOY9YoeJo8BS3HdfHCyhAeQAiTgAEgakhg0iTLRs8ZsIwFo3GEBAPDw5n4YmkeoNxtN93NfqtuEIUBsubBkGLpfLlf1RpNkepvnrloD+CIqWIk5gUxmczbpCAA):

```
const markdownText =
            '\
            * ![Allowed image](http://accepteddomain/image.png)\
            * ![Forbidden domain image](http://fordbidden/image.png) \
            * ![Forbiden IP image](http://80.11.20.15/image.png) \
            ';

const forbiddenImages = /!\[([^\]]+)\]\((.*(fordbidden|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*)\)/gm;

function removeForbidden(markdown: string): string {
    return  markdown.replace(forbiddenImages,"![$1] ()");
}

console.log(removeForbidden(markdownText)
```

I am getting only the first line of the input:

```
* ![Allowed image] ()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the issue come from the back slashes used inside the string. I have tried using ` and it's working:

```js
const markdownText =
            `
            * ![Allowed image](http://accepteddomain/image.png)
            * ![Forbidden domain image](http://fordbidden/image.png) 
            * ![Forbiden IP image](http://80.11.20.15/image.png)
            `;

const forbiddenImages = /!\[([^\]]+)\]\((.*(fordbidden|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*)\)/gm;

function removeForbidden(markdown: string) {
    return  markdown.replace(forbiddenImages,"![$1] ()");
}

console.log(removeForbidden(markdownText))
```

`

Comment: Thank you so much!!